# How to choose different robot footprint type for DWA_local_planner

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, eband-local-planner, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I wanted to know how the [DWA_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) computes (or chooses) the foorprint of the robot? is it a dot (or a circle based on the inflation added to the robot)? If yes, my question is that is it possible to give another type of the robot's foot print to the DWA_local_planner? (for example by line or two circle, something like the [TEB_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner)?

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275076/how-to-choose-different-robot-footprint-type-for-dwa_local_planner/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in your costmap config

if it is a circle you can set
`robot_radius: 0.35`

if it has a more complex shape, then represent is as a polygon:

`footprint: [[0.1, 0.0], [0.0, 0.1], [0.0, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.0]]`

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1